# Passing $(this) DOM element to function

Tags: jquery, function, timer, this

I am trying to create some sort of timer which I want to being able to fire for certain seconds and do a certain task when it's over:

Here is what I've got so far,

```
<span onclick='setTimeout(start_timer_j.call(this,event)'></span> "
```

When the text is clicked, a function jquery function is called

And this is the jquery function:

```
function start_timer_j(event){
    var el = $(this);
    var count = 1000;
    var counter= setInterval(timer, 100);
    function timer(this){
        $(this).text('k');
        count -=1;
    }
    el.text('k');
}
```

My problem is that passing this does not seem to make the variable known to the function, I also tried passing var el, and $(this). 
And a question, do u have any way in mind that I could also pause and replay the timer?

Thank you

Comment: That's not the correct way to use jQuery (and honestly, it's not the correct way to attach event handlers in modern Javascript too). Read about [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and you will see how to handle events and get `this` the right way too...

Comment: Okay, I'll check it out

Comment: By the way, `this` is a keyword which refers to different objects depending on the context. In your function's body it is referring to the function itself. You have to match the function's arguments between the definition and the call: ie: in your case the value assigned to `event` variable (it could be any other name) in the function's body is what you are after. But again, that's a pretty wrong way to code Javascript.

Comment: I know that this may not be the best way to code it,  I've been trying since yesterday to make this work in with many different approaches and I cant have it to work till now. I think that when passing variable el to the function code should work shouldnt it?

Comment: If you add another argument to the function and fix the `onclick` call (you missed some parenthesis, a wrapping function and the timeout delay) it should work. But again please read some documentation before starting to code, you will produce better code and waste no time writing things that *may* seem to work but in a kludgy way. See some examples: [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: @Eggplant Exactly! setTimeout() already does what Joe wants.

Answer (score 1):

I feel you are looking for something like:

```
<span onclick='setTimeout(start_timer_j(this, event), 0);'></span>

function start_timer_j(obj, event) {
       var el = $(obj);
       var count = 1000;
       var counter = setInterval(timer, 100);
        function timer(e) {

            el.text('k');
            count -=1;
        }
        el.text('k');
}
```

clearInterval(counter); and setInterval(timer, 100); can be used to pause and replay the timer.

Comment: I didnt expect that, but this works: http://pastebin.com/ErAQWbKS, thanks for feedback tho :)

Comment: Though it works but 'this' and 'event' are two different objects, e.g., event.x is property but nothing called this.x, it's undefined. So here 'this' object should a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the previous answer, this another way of doing the same thing.

`<span onclick='setTimeout(start_timer_j(event),0)'></span>`

```
function start_timer_j( event) {
       var el = $(event.currentTarget); //This will give you the originating element. Then wrap it in jQuery.
       var count = 1000;
       var counter = setInterval(timer, 100);
        function timer(e) {

            el.text('k');
            count -=1;
        }
        el.text('k');
}
```